# RegEx to extract & update a value

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to update the value in string. Here is my string

```
String strval = "in=app type=au act='Aut' check='abc|def|status||1234|4567|9080|x.x|ewer|www.yy.com|error'"

String pattern ="" -->need a help on this

result= strval.replaceAll(pattern , "success");
```

Basically i want to update the "status" string which will be after 2nd pipe. The string "status" may be any value, i want to update with "success"

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Is this fixed structure of your string. Can `check='abc|def|` appear twice or be value of some other attribute like `in="check='abc|def|status" check='abc|def|status|`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string is in the given format, I suppose you could do:

```
String result = strval.replaceFirst("(\\|[^|]*\\|)[^|]*", "$1success");
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/3xoc3R)

Comment: Thanks it works. one question, insted of 2nd pipe if i want to change the text at 6th pipe (ie word at 9080), how the regex patter should be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `check='abc|def|status|` can appear only once in your text you can try searching for it and storing `check='abc|def|` part in group which later you will reuse in replacement (via `$x` where `x` is group index).

So your code could be

```
String strval = "in=app type=au act='Aut' check='abc|def|status||1234|4567|9080|x.x|ewer|www.yy.com|error'";

String pattern = "(check='\\w+[|]\\w+[|])\\w+"; 
//                ^------ group 1 ------^  ^^-current value of `status`

String result = strval.replaceAll(pattern, "$1"+"success");
//                                          ^^-match from group 1
```